# QMAKE_CXXFLAGS doesn't work

Tags: linux, compiler-warnings, qt5

I'm reading everywhere that to add flags to the compiler we have to, inside the .pro, add command like this:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wimplicit-function-declaration
```

Right, I'm under Linux 64bit, Qt5 and adding this inside my .pro doesn't change anything

It turns out that I don't see the flag inside the compilation line, and the CXXFLAGS inside the **Makefile** generated does not contain my flag !?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that sometimes qmake is a bit lazy and won't regenerate the Makefile even though the .pro has changed. Try rebuilding everything, or at least deleting the Makefile.

Comment: You're right man... Is it a bug ? I don't know.Good answer !!

Comment: I haven't been able to pinpoint where does it come from... It definitely doesn't happen every time (I just tried adding your line into one of my projects and it worked straight away).

Comment: Mhh got another problem now.. :( I add QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = -Wno-unused-parameter, I can see it inside the makefile, but running the makefile displays "warning: unused parameter 'len' [-Wunused-parameter]" !?

Comment: Weird. Maybe you have a -Wall hanging around somewhere, or something else superseding the option at some point (beware of = vs +=). It's hard to tell without more information. I recommend you post another question adding maybe the makefile or the .pro (or part of them) if you can't find why it happens.